# How to override values in the 'build-info.properties' file at the time of bootstrapping a Spring Boot application jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application that generates a `build-info.properties` file during the build process. The build-info.properties file contains static build metadata such as the project name, description, version, build timestamp, etc (that we define in pom.xml).

When Bootstrapping the jar file I want to override build.name and build.description. That I read using Autowired `BuildProperties` object.

Right now, It only contains properties configured in `pom.xml` file.

**Why I am doing this?**
I want to deploy `service-a` Artifact with another name as `service-b` with overridden values. Also, I want to restrict myself from changing source code of `service-a` instead provide command-line args, environment variables, etc to override this configuration.

Comment: Why? It is build-info, information about the build? It doesn't use the name of the service. If you want to rename your application just provide a `spring.application.name` and be done.

Comment: Actually, there are multiple services which were using this BuildProps object for extracting project name. And I am refraining from making any code change. Instead utilizing externalize config that updates specific attributes (just hoping if any easy way out)

Comment: Well if you want to change those you can only do that at build time. The `spring.application.name` you can provide as a startup parameter.